# Does meta_query work within get_posts array?

Tags: query, get-posts

I can't seem to get this to work — I'm trying to show posts that have the meta 'featured_image' value set to anything. From what I can tell, it's set up correctly, but I'm in a little over my head. Here's what I have:

```
 <ul>
  <?php
    global $post;
    $myposts = get_posts(array(
      'showposts' => 5,
      'offset' => 7,
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'featured_image',
          'value' => '',
          'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
          )
        )
    ));
    foreach($myposts as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post);
      $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '');
  ?>
    <li>
      <a href=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php if (isset($meta['featured_image'][0]) && !empty($meta['featured_image'][0])): echo $meta['featured_image'][0]; else: ?>/wp-content/themes/SSv2011/images/review-default.gif<?php endif; ?>&w=84&h=60" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
  <?php unset($myposts); ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
```

Updated to show the entire query. Any ideas? :\

---

Updated to WP_Query and I'm getting posts to appear, but they're not ONLY posts that have something inside 'featured_image'. Any ideas with that? The new query:

```
      <?php
      $args = array(
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key' => 'featured_image',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
            )
          )
      );
      $ft_pagination = new WP_Query( $args );
      ?>
      <?php while ($ft_pagination->have_posts()) : $ft_pagination->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $ftimage = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'featured_image', TRUE); ?>
        <li>
          <article>
            <a href="">
            <?php if ($ftimage): ?>
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $ftimage; ?>&w=84&h=60" alt="" />
            <?php else: ?>
              <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/themes/ssv/images/review-default.gif&w=84&h=60" alt="" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
          </article>
        </li>
      <?php
      endwhile;

      wp_reset_query();
      ?>
```

Comment: Why not use wp_query

Comment: `compare` is spelt wrong in the above(and your `get_post_meta` call is missing a key), are either of those the problem? (if you want to look at pages, you'll need to set the post type).

Comment: Just caught that — Thanks! Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The missing `get_post_meta` key is the `$single` which doesn't need set, right? It works for every other query I've created.

Comment: @bainternet I didn't set these up originally, so I'm not sure... Like I said — I'm in a little over my head. ;o)

Comment: Well `meta_query` works fine for me with `get_posts`, but no i meant the second `get_post_meta` parameter in your call which is suppose to be the `meta_key` to get data for. If you're wanting to check pages you'll need to explicitly set that as the post type in the args.

Comment: @Rob t31os is right your get_post_meta is missing the meta_key so its looking for a meta value of a key named '' which i bet is not your meta field name, also when using meta_query you can set the "compare" to  "NOT LIKE" instead of != .

Comment: Thanks guys — I've posted the entire query to see if it makes more sense to you. There are multiple keys that I call for different posts, so I'm not sure that setting the key there works for me. If you have an example though, I'd love to see it. Even so — would that affect the meta_query?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with an empty value. See: [How can I show posts only if meta_value is not empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty)

Comment: This is fixed in WP 3.2 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your `get_post_meta` call doesn't have a key, shouldn't that be `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_image', true )` or `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_image', false )` if you want multiple values.

Additionally you're treating the results of the `get_post_meta` call like it has an array of values here `$meta['featured_image'][0]`, yet you've not specified a key, meaning it's highly unlikely to contain anything at that point.

I suspect the lack of key in the `get_post_meta` call is the main issue.

Addtitionally i'd suggest moving back to the `!=` operator, `NOT LIKE` wouldn't really be appropriate for an empty string comparison, imagine how that SQL will look.

```
WHERE meta_value NOT LIKE '%%'
```

Where as using the not equals comparison we get..

```
WHERE meta_value != ''
```

..which is(i believe) exactly what we intend to check for, a meta field with a value that is anything but an empty value.

Comment: Tried it — got nothing. :o\ Is this even possible within get_posts? Someone else mentioned I may need to use query_posts.

Comment: It works for me, dump some of your vars and check they contain what you're expecting them to, eg. `$meta` and `$myposts`

Comment: $meta contains `[featured_image] => Array ( [0] => /wp-content/uploads/2011/02/ThisImage.jpg` - Seems to be there...

Comment: Ok @t31os - I've updated my query to WP_Query and am now setting the key... I'm now getting posts returned, but it's grabbing any post - not just the ones with a value in featured_image. Edited the post to show the new query above.

Comment: Still works for me just fine, try passing the surpress filters arg, eg. `'surpress filters' => true`, to bypass any filters that might be hooked on by a plugin or function, and again remember to explicitly set the post type if you're fetching anything not posts, eg. `'post_type' => 'your-type'`.